# How to visualize a school schedule?

Tags: gui-design

I'm trying to figure out a good way to present todays lessons for students in an app. I'm not bound to anything (except maybe Microsoft Design Language) and I want to be innovative and modern.

The current way I present todays lessons is a list like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqwMA.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having written a similar web-service for my university, I can share a few things that our usability studies uncovered:

- The most important piece of information from students' perspective was the time when the first lesson started, and when the last one finished :)
- Duration of each class is virtually useless info: partly because most classes have the same length anyways, partly because it has no impact on your decision-making.
- What is important however, is the duration of breaks between classes. Is it 5 mins? 15? 2 hours? This all has crucial importance for a student.
- Another important piece of info to display (if you can get that info) is an estimate of the distance between classrooms.
- Your app should be able to detect if the class occurs at a different location or time than usual, in which case it should **emphasize** this fact very prominently.
- If such information exists in your university's DB, your application could also display special flags if the class expects a homework or if there will be test / mid-term / exam during the class. Although students should know all this themselves, there are always a few who forget :)

Answer (score 7):

Current setup doesn't tell students (visually) how long a lesson really is. It's just a list of items. How about putting lessons into a calendar where your students see the length of a lesson, an (for some students mor importantly) the break between lessons.

And while your at it - color code your lessons so you associate a color to english another color to chemistry and so on. That way you're users will know (after a while using your app) just by quickly looking at your app - what's next and what the day looks like.

As the following:

[image]